# PHP DomDocument inside an existing div

Tags: php, html, class, multidimensional-array, domdocument

I would like the DomDocument inside this "wrap" div.

```
<div id="wrap">
    The created divs should display inside this div called "wrap".<br/>
</div>

<?php
//this array value normally comes from a database, which has no consistent data.
$row = array(   "test1"=>
                        array ("first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth"),
               "test2"=>
                        array("one", "two", "three", "four", "five"));


foreach($row as $val){

    $DOMObject = new DOMDocument();

    $root_element = $DOMObject->createElement("div", "____Name(test1/2) that doesnt work for a reason, says its an array but so is the content inside___");
    $DOMObject->appendChild($root_element);

    $root_element_attribute = $DOMObject->createAttribute("class");
    $root_element->appendChild($root_element_attribute);

    $root_element_attribute_value = $DOMObject->createTextNode("name of array");
    $root_element_attribute->appendChild($root_element_attribute_value);


    foreach($val as $val2){

        $root_element2 = $DOMObject->createElement("div", $val2);
        $root_element->appendChild($root_element2);

        $root_element_attribute2 = $DOMObject->createAttribute("class");
        $root_element2->appendChild($root_element_attribute2);

        $root_element_attribute_value2 = $DOMObject->createTextNode($val2);
        $root_element_attribute2->appendChild($root_element_attribute_value2);

    };
    echo $DOMObject->saveXML();
};
```

I can't seem to find out how to do it. i have searched topics from here and http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php but i don't understand how it works, there are no examples for me to fiddle with. $row also doesn't show "test1" and "test2" as value when used in "echo", it gives an error that it cant display an array, while the other array value shows fine.

Replacing "new DOMDocument();" with codes below doesn't work either.

```
    $DOMObject = new DOMDocument();
    $DOMObject = $xpath->query("//*[@id='wrap']");
```

or

```
    $DOMObject = new DOMDocument();
    @$DOMObject->loadHTML($html);
    $DOMObject->getElementById('wrap');
```

And is it normal that it shows ?xml version="1.0"? in html? can that be made hidden?

Comment: As said in ym answer of your other question, you can get rid of the xml declaration by using `$dom = new DOMImplementation;
  $doc = $dom->createDocument(null, 'html', $dom->createDocumentType('html'));` To create you document. It will show the html5 doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: This is a bit old but did you found a solution to this problem? MAybe i can helpyou on this one too

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, Without DOMDocument knowledge its weird to see `<?xml version="1.0"?>` if you don't know exactly what it means or that it could create a security flaw. In my case i wanted to neatly use the DOMDocument in the top of the script without opening and closing PHP all the time. But you can just open PHP inside a `<div>` and build from there. But i'm always curious if the script can be placed into a existing pre made `<div>`.

Comment: is the div 'hard-coded/hand-crafted' (like plain text html) or is it generated by DOMDocument? From what i see in your example, the div is hand creafted. Both way are possible but parsing the html from scrach ( hand-made) is a bit more work.

Comment: hand-crafted then, It's not logical to do this, I just wanted the PHP to be on top of my script without knowing that you can put PHP anywhere without immediate security risks. Perhaps someone else is looking for this weird code.